# Encryption algorithm in 4k memory

Tags: security, encryption

i am working in some devices (hardware) for domotic aplications, now i need to implement an algorithm to avoid intruders in my network deploy by the devices, the only restriction i have is that the memory in each device is 4k, any suggestion that i can implement??

Comment: In C, C++ or in the assembly code for your particular embedded CPU. Mention the type.

Comment: Are you talking about 4kB RAM, or a code size of 4kB?

Comment: The description of what you're trying to prevent is a bit unclear too, so I can't tell you if you need symmetric or asymmetric encryption, or if your goal is plain impossible.

Comment: You really shouldn't implement an encryption algorithm yourself but use an established implementation. It's incredibly difficult to implement an encryption algorithm that is both bug-free and resiliant to side-channel attacks and such.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Sebastian, please follow up on the comments.

Answer (score 0):

4k is a huge amount of memory for any cryptographic implementation.  A block cipher such as AES-128 encrypts 16 byte blocks at a time.  Any mode of operation can be performed (nearly) in-place so you don't need to make a copy of the data you are encrypting/decrypting.  Also CBC mode is a good choice.

Symmetric Cryptography is very light weight,  I am not sure why memory or even CPU requirements would be a concern.  This would have been a concern 30 or more years ago. But certainly not when you have 4,096 bytes of memory!

Comment: What is a "cartographic implantation"?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't my intention. I don't know too much about cryptography and thought it was some technical jargon, which is why I asked.